Is there an way to go around the "Field 'id' expected a number" when dealing with a queryset?
I am working on a learning platform. I want to be able to track user progress of the chapters completed. I cerated a new model and inserted it into the html using a form. However when I submit, I keep getting a TypeError with the specifics that "Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['YMvOO6ZYGWVVfxfgoFLVEanZ9zK70CrqlRIx5Y2LOkbzH8Mx3UHPlQYczqLbq1Qt'], 'chapter': ['2'], 'completed': ['on'], 'student': ['1']}>"
I tried converting all the variables I was using to identify the user, student and chapter to their primary keys but I got even more complicated error. If there is an easier way to track the progress or a tutorial on a way to do it, please share.
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.0.118:8000/learn/jerome/mathematics/addition/using-you-fingers

Django Version: 5.0.6
Python Version: 3.12.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'learn']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2117, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'QueryDict') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapper_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\kptt\learn\views.py", line 109, in chapter_dashboard
    form = StudentProgressForm(
           
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\kptt\learn\forms.py", line 26, in __init__
    student_queryset = Student.objects.filter(user=user, student_slug=student_slug)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1476, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1494, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1501, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1613, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1645, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
                                 
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1559, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1389, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 156, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KAMBAFWILE JOSEPH\OneDrive\Documents\Web\django\learn\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2119, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
    ^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: TypeError at /learn/jerome/mathematics/addition/using-you-fingers
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['YMvOO6ZYGWVVfxfgoFLVEanZ9zK70CrqlRIx5Y2LOkbzH8Mx3UHPlQYczqLbq1Qt'], 'chapter': ['2'], 'completed': ['on'], 'student': ['1']}>.


Here's what I tried
This is he StudemtProgress Model
class StudentProgress(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_progress"
    )
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(
        Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_progress"
    )
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    

This is the form. Some of the code is to pick only the current logged in user and the chapter of th page that it is being displayed.
class StudentProgressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProgress
        fields = ("chapter", "completed", "student")
        # widgets = {
        #     "student": forms.HiddenInput(),
        # }

    def __init__(self, user, student_slug, chapter_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentProgressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        student_queryset = Student.objects.filter(user=user, student_slug=student_slug)

        if student_queryset.exists():
            self.instance.student = student_queryset.first()
        else:
            self.instance.student = None

        if student_queryset.exists():
            self.fields["student"].initial = student_queryset.first()

        current_chapter = Chapter.objects.filter(chapter_slug=chapter_slug).first()
        self.fields["chapter"].initial = current_chapter

    def get_current_chapter(self, current_chapter_slug):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(chapter_slug=current_chapter_slug).first()

This is the logic I used in the views.py file
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentProgressForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=single_chapter,
            student_slug=student_slug,
            chapter_slug=chapter_slug,
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("user_dashboard")

    else:
        form = StudentProgressForm(
            user=request.user,
            instance=single_chapter,
            student_slug=student_slug,
            chapter_slug=chapter_slug,
        )

And lastly the html file has this form
<form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

I have done so, please advise. Thanks in advance

In views.py for POST request, you don't specify the user field when initializing the StudentProgressForm. without specifying the user field, when the form is processed request.POST represents a QueryDict not a user , which causes errors.
You can resolve this by modifying the form and the view as follows:
In StudentProgressForm:
def __init__(self, user, student_slug, chapter_slug, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

In the view:
form = StudentProgressForm(
    data=request.POST,
    user=request.user
    instance=single_chapter,
    student_slug=student_slug,
    chapter_slug=chapter_slug,
)

Also to reduce the extra querys you can try this:
def __init__(self, user, student_slug, chapter_slug, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
    student_queryset = Student.objects.filter(user=user, student_slug=student_slug)
    
    student = student_queryset.first() #  if  student not exists then default well be None
    self.instance.student = student
    self.fields["student"].initial = student

    current_chapter = Chapter.objects.filter(chapter_slug=chapter_slug).first()
    self.fields["chapter"].initial = current_chapter


There's no value in passing a data attribute to the form - it doesn't get consumed there. The critical takeaway is that OP was declaring form = StudentProgressForm(request.POST, instead of form = StudentProgressForm(request.user,, the rest is fluff.

You were right, I had to remove the data attribute. However, please further advise as the form is not saving

@JeromeKambafwile Could you provide more details? Is form.is_valid() returning True? Are you being redirected to the user_dashboard but the data is not being saved?   Are you encountering any specific errors?  You can also add some print statements to trace the steps and see what's happening with the data.
